# Генерация случайного 32-х значного числа

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Добрый вечер!

Каким образом можно сгенерировать случайное 32-х значное число на Objective-C?

Если, конечно, такое возможно.

ДОБАВЛЕНО:

Десятичное 32-х значное число. Например "91525125864535235496832953428533"

Comment: 32-значное - это 32 десятичные цифры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Objective C [настоятельно рекомендуется `arc4random_uniform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163178/276994). Поскольку он возвращает не более чем `uint32_t`, вам придётся накопить несколько таких значений.

Максимум, который можно получить у `uint32_t`, равен 4294967296. 
У вас всего *N* = 90000000000000000000000000000000 значений (от "1000...0" до "9999...9"), двоичный логарифм этого числа даёт log<sub>2</sub>(9 × 10<sup>31</sup>) = log<sub>2</sub> 9 + 31 × log<sub>2</sub> 10, около 106.15, значит, нам нужно по крайней мере 107 случайных бит. Для этого трёх `uint32_t` недостаточно (это даст лишь 32 × 3 = 92 случайных бит), а вот четырёх — вполне.

Таким образом, проблема может быть решена за 4 вызова `arc4random_uniform`. Чтобы было проще, пусть все они дают нам по 8 цифр, а причём последний не начинается с 0.

Получаем для первого, второго и третьего вызовов

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08d", arc4random_uniform(100000000)]
```

Для последнего вам нужно получить число в промежутке `[10000000, 100000000)` (включая левую границу и исключая правую), что даёт 90000000 различных значений. Получаем

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 10000000 + arc4random_uniform(90000000)]
```

Осталось сконкатенировать эти четыре строки в нужном порядке.

Получить результат в виде *числа* не представляется возможным: таких больших чисел Objective C не знает.

---

Если же вам нужно число, 32-значное в *двоичной* системе (а я думаю, именно так и есть), используйте просто `arc4random`.

Comment: На самом деле есть еще вариант [собрать C библиотеку вроде BN из OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html) и использовать генератор оттуда. Там отдельный тип BIGNUM вместо обычных строк, для которого реализована арифметика и проверка простоты. Еще есть [GNU multiple precision](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Если применение не критичное - 32 раза вызвать random(), привести его результат к диапазону [0,9], прибавить к результату '0', добавить к строке то что получилось.